# How to Get Move From Minimax Algorithm in Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

So far I have successfully been able to use the Minimax algorithm in Python and apply it to a tic-tac-toe game. I can have my algorithm run through the whole search treee, and return a value.

However, I am confused as to how to take this value, and transform it into a move? How am I supposed to know which move to make?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use a recursive algorithm? If so, in addition to returning the final value, you can also return the corresponding move at each step, and get your move when you're done with the whole unstacking.

Comment: How have you successfully been able to use minimax if you don't understand how to use the value?  I'm confused where exactly you're having trouble.

Comment: @user189 Yes, I am using a recursive algorithm. Thanks, i'll try that. How is the program supposed to know it is at the end though? Since it is recursive, I don't think it'd do to have a move returned every time it does its thing.

Comment: @twinlakes At the moment, I can use the minimax algorithm to get the heuristic value of the current node.

Comment: I can see two possibilities. First one, you return the move for each call, and your main call will automatically get the next move. Second one, you use an additional parameter (say "isFirst"), if isFirst then set isFirst to False and return the move.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptualize the minimax algorithm like a graph, where every vertex is a possible configuration of the board, and every edge from a vertex to its neighbor is a transition/move from one board configuration to the next.

You need to look at the heuristic value of each board state neighboring your current state, then choose the state with the best heuristic value, then update your screen to show that board state.

If you are doing animations/transitions between board states, then you would have to look at the edge and figure out which piece is different between the two states, and animate that piece accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In using the MM algorithm, you must have had a way to generate the possible successor boards; each of those was the result of a move.  As has been suggested, you can modify your algorithm to include tracking of the move that was used to generate a board (for example, adding it to the definition of a board, or using a structure that has the board and the move); or, you could have a special case for the top level of the algorithm, since that is the only one in which the particular move is important.

For example, if your function currently returns just the computed value of the board it was passed, it could instead return a dict (or tuple, which isn't as clear) with both the value and the first move used to obtain that value, and then modify your code to use whichever bit is needed.

Comment: It is this tracking that I am having trouble with. For example, if I try to return the board, it messes up my algorithm because of minimaxes recursion.

I am afraid that if I try to make a special case for the top level only, it won't allow the program to do its searching.

In pseudocode, how might I implement this kind of tracking?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to select your move is to choose your move that has the maximum number of winning positions stemming from that move.

I would, for each node in your search tree (game state) keep a record of possible win states that can be created by the current game state.